# Browser Popup Blocker is turned off/on

Tags: php, browser

Is their any way can I check in PHP that my brower(s) FF/Chrome/IE/Safari popup blocker is allowed/enabled or not?

Comment: I think there is no way.
you may try some javascript like this 
[Test For Popup Blocker Using JavaScript](http://davidwalsh.name/popup-block-javascript)

Comment: What do you mean by "allowed" ? You have a PHP file, and you call it with a browser that has a popup blocker, right? So who decides when to allow something and on what grounds? You need to tell this first probably before we can tell you if you can. Or I'm just not getting your question, please clarify.

Comment: @BasicBridge: yeah best alternative!

Comment: Keep in mind: PHP is serverside, that means, php don't know a bit of a browser. JavaScript should be your frind

Comment: @Nanne: actually we verify the credientials through PHP and and redirect to that site, I think it is possible through JS

Comment: As a response to @donald123, PHP might know "a bit" about the browser, but just whatever is on the request headers. That incluides the user-agent headers which tells you exactly which browser is the user using, and your strategy to show your info can be dependant on the user-agent (Pretty much what web pages do for showing mobile version when browsing from the mobile browser) .

Comment: @hectorg87 "That incluides the user-agent headers which tells you exactly which browser is the user using ..." this is not given! These Informations are not trusted and can be changed by browser configuration, usermanipulation etc ... so never trust those infos

Comment: @donald123 that's right, this information can be tampered easily, however is not like you can't trust it at all. You are not going to make your business mission critical process depend on the user-agent, however it can be used and if a user changes it and his user experience gets down because of that is his problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popup blockers can only be detected on the client, however perhaps you could do something like this:

- Fire a test popup and close it with javascript immediately. During the process detect if the popup was successful or blocked.
- Once that is done, fire an AJAX request to your server and save whether you were blocked by the popup blocker in a session variable.

However, I don't really see why your server side code would need to know if the client has an active popup blocker, unless you are collecting the data for statistical purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that :

```
<script language="javascript">

var myWindow;

myWindow= window.open(...);
if (myWindow.closed) {
    //pop up disabled
}

</script>
```

But it's not in PHP ^^

Answer (score 1):

Because PHP is a Server Side language I'm positive it won't be possible using only PHP. Do as the other answers have said and use Javascript for this task (maybe AJAX?).

PHP might know "a bit" about the browser, but just whatever is on the request headers. That incluides the **user-agent** headers which tells you exactly which browser is the user using, and your strategy to show your info can be dependant on the user-agent (Pretty much what web pages do for showing mobile version when browsing from the mobile browser) .